# Using Python libraries without installing them globally

Tags: python, pythonpath, egg

I have a python script that I want to deploy to various PCs to run tests, and I need to use the third-party library `pysnmp`. Since I don't want to have to manually install `pysnmp` on every target PC, I figured I could just put `pysnmp` (and related) `eggs` in an `eggs/` directory and just append that to the python path before importing:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("./eggs/pysnmp-4.2.5-py3.4.egg")
sys.path.append("./eggs/pyasn1-0.1.7-py3.3.egg")
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
```

This works as expected as long as I execute the script in the directory containing `eggs/`, however it seems rather manual and messy. Is there a portable way to tell python to just search through `[path to module]/eggs/` anytime I want to import?

Comment: have you tried using an absolute path that you compute at runtime based on the directory component of `__file__`?

Comment: Why not create a virtualenv on each machine and install `pysnmp` and your module into each virtualenv? You could write a simple script to do this so that you don't need to do things "manually".

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks, I hadn't tried that, and yes, it works and solves the problem of relative paths.

Comment: @jme The whole point is, I don't want to have to "set up" each target PC... I just want to "fire and forget". Can I create a virtualenv with `pysnmp` pre-installed and then push *that* to the target PC?

Comment: The amount of "setup" is really minimal. You could make a bash script to make a virtualenv, install `pysnmp` and your code in probably three lines. Push *this* to each machine and run it. That's pretty portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I use is to get the directory of the script (eg: `os.path.dirname(__file__)`), and then use the absolute path of that when adding to `sys.path`.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because I got it to work and is simple, even though the other answer is probably a better long-term solution.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`.  These are very common and widely used methods of creating non-global environments for Python programs.

Here's a good intro:

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: I like this solution, but it seems non-portable (i.e. each virtual environment is locked to the computer you created it on). Or am I just missing something?

Comment: @RPGillespie: not really, the steps to create the virtualenv can be run on other systems and that'll install the packages there. A virtualenv only isolates the packages from other Python installations, it doesn't tie it to a particular architecture.

Comment: @RPGillespie This gets into a long conversation, but basically you'll want to package your module (see https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html for details). Do that, and it'll be very easy to install your module and all of its dependencies in a virtualenv on any machine. This is a standard practice.

Comment: I like the idea of this solution, but it just seems like python packaging is way harder than it should be. Sometimes I wish it were like `npm` or something so I could just deploy my script(s) + a json file of the dependencies.